# Why I can't split the string?

Tags: shell, aix

I want to read a file by shell script, and process it line by line. I would like to extract 2 fields from each line. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bsh
mlist=`ls *.log.2011-11-1* | grep -v error`
for log in $mlist
do
        while read line
        do
                echo ${line} | awk -F"/" '{print $4}'  #This produce nothing
                echo ${line}                           #This work and print each line
        done < $log | grep "java.lang.Exception"
done
```

This is a sample line from the input file:

```
<ERROR> LimitFilter.WebContainer : 4 11-14-2011 21:56:55 - java.lang.Exception: File - /AAA/BBB/CCC/DDDDDDDD.PDF does not exist
```

If I don't use bsh, I can use ksh, and the result is the same. We have no bash here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are passing the output of your while loop through `grep "java.lang.Exception"`.

The output of  `echo $line | awk -F"/" '{print $4}'` is `CCC`. When this is piped through `grep`, nothing is printed because `CCC` does not match the search pattern.

Try removing `| grep "java.lang.Exception"` and you will see the output of your loop come out correctly.

An alternative approach to take might be to remove the while loop and instead just use:

```
grep "java.lang.Exception" $log | awk -F"/" '{print $4}'
```

Comment: ic...I thought I've processing the input by grep. Never know it is the output processed by the grep.